# there is some sort of error in the syntax of the program "to determine whether the number is prime or not" in JAVA

Tags: java

Even if I input the number "4", it shows that the number is prime. Please help to find error in the syntax. I have written below the program I coded :

int n  = sc.nextInt();

```
boolean isPrime = true;

for (int i = 2;  i < n; i = i + 1)
{if (n % i == 0) {
    isPrime = false;
    break;}
}

if (isPrime = true) 
    System.out.println("the number is prime");

else if (isPrime = false)
System.out.println("the number is not prime");
```

Comment: `if (isPrime = true) ` try `==`

Comment: This is the only way to mess up primitive comparison in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boolean comparison needs to be done with double equals `==`. The way you have it currently, you are setting `isPrime` to be `true` in that check. Try this:

```
if (isPrime == true)
```

Comment: Yes it worked well ! This "=" operator was the mistake . Thankyou !

Answer (score 0):

Your program is not complete. You have written assignment statement instead of boolean expression in if statement. '=' sign is for assignment, As 'isPrime' is a boolean variable you can write isPrime in if expression

```
if(isPrime)
{
System.out.println("the number is prime");

}
else
{
System.out.println("the number is not prime");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Equality operator `==` instead of assignment operator `=` for checking the value of `isPrime`.

Your code should be:

```
boolean isPrime = true;

for (int i = 2;  i < n; i = i + 1)
{if (n % i == 0) {
    isPrime = false;
    break;}
}

if (isPrime == true) 
    System.out.println("the number is prime");

else
   System.out.println("the number is not prime");
```

Also,since if() method's return type is boolean, you can directly check with using ```==````

```
boolean isPrime = true;

for (int i = 2;  i < n; i = i + 1)
{if (n % i == 0) {
    isPrime = false;
    break;}
}

if (isPrime) 
    System.out.println("the number is prime");

else
   System.out.println("the number is not prime");
```